# Identifying internal structures of dissected fish

Tags: zoology, anatomy, ichthyology, dissection, species-identification

**Note : Images displayed below might be disturbing to some people.**

I have dissected a fish for the first time ! I have some idea of what some of the structures might be but I am not sure and so would like your help.

1.Here is the fish I dissected. Are the white structures (towards the dorsal surface) muscles ? They are beautifully arranged.

[image]

2.I want to know what the yellow coloured structure (towards the ventral side) is. I guess it's the intestine. It looks "noodly". Here is a close up.
[image]

3.I have pointed at two different parts in the following images. I want to know whether they are part of the same structure - ie swim bladder or whether they are two different structures altogether. When I poked one of the parts the other part increased in size ,so I guess it's one structure but I just wanna make sure.[image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't actually look at and handle the yellow structures, it is difficult for me to provide any information on them.

As far as the white structures you mention on the first picture, I believe those are most likely muscles. 
As for your third question. That does appear to be all one structure; and yes, going on that assumption, the entire structure would be the swim bladder.

Comment: Thanks! You can see the white structure very well in the second picture. I am pretty sure the yellow stuff isn't fat. I am actually confused between calling it intestine or pyloric seca.

Comment: A swim bladder in two parts is a common thing. At least I remember having seen at least in some of the few fish dissection I've made.